# Sliding Tabs Jquery Plugin - How to diable mousewheel functionality?

Tags: jquery, plugins, mousewheel, slidertabs

I'm using Sliding Tabs Jquery Plugin which have mouse wheel scrolling facilities ON as default value. Below is the ref url from where I use code. 
http://mauriceaquilina.com/build/slidingtabs

Now I don't need mouse wheel scrolling. How can I disable that?

I have already used  below codes.

```
mousewheel : false,
tabsScroll: false,
```

but they are not working even after installing JQuery MouseWheel Plugin. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you mean _uninstalling_? If you don't want mouse wheel support then try not including the mousewheel plugin.

Comment: Yes I don't want mouse wheel effect support. Initially mousewheel plugin was not added but just to disabled I tried installing plugin too. But nothing is working well.

Comment: Please remove jquery plugin file "jquery.mousewheel.min.js"

Comment: is the plugin new home page http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got solution for this. In the JQuery file I update below code and now my mouse wheel is disabled..

Previous :

```
f.bind("mousewheel", function (a, b, c, e)
```

Change to:

```
f.unbind("mousewheel", function (a, b, c, e)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
Previous:
`$container.bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                if(delta > 0)
                    plugin.next();
                else if(delta < 0)
                    plugin.prev();
                return false;
            });`
Change to:

```
$container.unbind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            if(delta > 0)
                plugin.next();
            else if(delta < 0)
                plugin.prev();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: This seems to work better for me, thanks user4533280

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-slider-tabs.panel {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

just add css to main class `.ui-slider-tabs.panel`

```
pointer-event: none;
```

This is working for me in Firefox and chrome